# "How can I compare and contrast open source licenses?" - canonical dupe for license shopping?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, licensing

While pondering upon today's [usual license shopping request](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/256092/31260) I discovered this old question:

- **[How can I compare and contrast open source licenses?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/120308/31260)**

Would it make sense to make above a [canonical duplicate target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217406/165773) for license shopping questions? Possibly along with [collaborative effort lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182572/165773) on its answer(s).

As a regular question it doesn't look like a good fit for the site, more like a candidate to be closed and deleted. Question per se reads [too broad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490) and the answers tend to refer readers to ["another castle"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773).

But it somehow managed to outline basic research effort I would expect of askers before they dump their "license requirments" at us. As such, would it make a convenient dupe target?

Comment: To me, the "How can I compare..." question reads like a request for external resources, and the answers happily oblige. The question and answers need some serious rework to become a viable canonical duplicate in my view.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau agree. To start with, I'd cut question itself to first two sentences, "My company has given permission for me to open source some internal tools I've built. The first step is to choose an open source license. How do I do this?" - the rest looks simply useless. For a regular question this would be too short and vague though, I don't have enough experience to tell if it would be okay for canonical. As for answers... I took a second look and yeah need _quite_ some work

Comment: What we _really_ need here are more features in the tag wiki system. Like (perhaps) the ability to mark a question a duplicate _of_ a tag wiki page, and easier 'wiki like' creation and linking together of pages. I plan to tackle that after we're done with the quality project.

Comment: @TimPost great idea, I think feature like you describe could make a really efficient solution for cases like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel this question is a good canonical target for "License Shopping" questions as it is overtly broad and would give users the wrong impression about what kinds of questions are okay to ask here.

I am not sure that there can be a canonical answer for license shopping that isn't overtly broad.  I think the best solution is to try to improve the quality of existing and future license shopping questions to where they are specific and present a real problem that the OP faces.  If this question gets a great focused answer then we can use that specific question as a dupe target for future questions that are highly similar.

Eg. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236370/query-regarding-mit-licence being a duplicate of the better question [MIT and copyright](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/mit-and-copyright)

The latter question can be a canonical dupe for questions about copyright as it pertains to utilizing software components that have the MIT License.